Plugin grapesjs-preset-newsletter not found
I am trying to integrate grapejs to my wordpress site. I am following the below links
https://github.com/GrapesJS/preset-newsletter/tree/master
https://github.com/GrapesJS/blocks-basic
I loaded both js files

The editor is initialized and the js files are also loaded. But I am getting plugin not found.

Below is my js code
    jQuery(function(){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            var editor = grapesjs.init({
                container : '#gjs',
                plugins: ['grapesjs-preset-newsletter', "gjs-blocks-basic"],
                pluginsOpts: {
                'grapesjs-preset-newsletter': {
                    // options
                },
                "gjs-blocks-basic":{
        
                }
                }
            });
        

        })
    
    })

This issue was addressed in 2018, but they suggest to go with requirejs. I tried to include requirejs into my wordpress app and I am getting lots of error.
https://github.com/GrapesJS/grapesjs/issues/902
Has anyone tried to use GrapeJS plugins on plain JS.
